# androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.view.MenuItem

Tags: android, android-fragments, menuitem, androidx

I'm having an issue trying to hide certain items from the menu of the toolbar when a particular fragment is active. (Edit: the toolbar is not set as an ActionBar in this case)

I've been looking around for a solution and found out that you can set the visibility of an MenuItem, I tried to implement this but I'm getting an error stating that MenuItem is actually an ActionMenuItemView.

I don't know if that is related to the fact that I'm using Androidx. Afterwards, I tried replacing MenuItem by ActionMenuItemView to find if there was a method that could hide the views but couldn't find any.
here's my code (in this case i want to hide the refresh icon on the toolbar when the back up fragment is active) :

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



private Toolbar toolbar2;


final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment fragment2 = new ReportFragment();
final Fragment fragment3 = new BackupFragment();
final Fragment fragment4 = new SettingFragment();
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment active = fragment1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //Setting up the Toolbar
    toolbar2 = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_2);
    toolbar2.inflateMenu(R.menu.test_menu);

    //Setting bottom navaigation view
    BottomNavigationView navigation =  findViewById(R.id.navigation);
       navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment4, "4").hide(fragment4).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment1, "1").commit();

    }

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    toolbar2.setTitle("Submitted Reports");
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_report:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    toolbar2.setTitle("Templates Reports");
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_backup:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    toolbar2.setTitle("Upload Reports");
                    MenuItem refresh = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.action_refresh);
                    refresh.setVisible(false);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_setting:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment4).commit();
                    active = fragment4;
                    toolbar2.setTitle("Settings");

                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
```

the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
tools:context="com.shid.form.UI.HomeActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="@color/primary">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar

    android:id="@+id/toolbar_2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Popup"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.GuidelinesCompat.Toolbar"
    app:title="Submitted Reports" />





<!-- Fragments Container -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
<include
layout="@layout/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

/>
</FrameLayout>
    <!-- app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"-->

<!-- Bottom Navigation View -->

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    />

  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Your MenuItem is the `item` variable.

Comment: Yes I would to hide it when a particular fragment is active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out where the problem was, for some reason overriding onCreateOptionsMenu didn't work out for me, so I found another way:

```
toolbar2.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);
```

So in my case since I want to hide the item when a particular fragment is active I created two methods and call them depending on the fragment:

```
 private void hideMenuItems(){
    toolbar2.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(false);
    toolbar2.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
}

private void revealMenuItems(){
    toolbar2.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_refresh).setVisible(true);
    toolbar2.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will only work if you set the `Toolbar` as `ActionBar` first. (Deleting my answer because it's not helpful in your situation) The variable name "toolbar2" seems to indicate you really use a second `Toolbar`, could you edit your question and say so explicitly to avoid future misunderstandings? One more thing: you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) to show the problem is solved